# How to create percentage change column in Tableau

Tags: pandas, tableau-desktop

Have a table based on Covid-19 data from the Department of Health (UK).

[image]

So far so nice. But I want to create an extra column for the percentage change. I am still learning. I'll add the data although it has been modified - there is a question about how I did that in Pandas. [How to transform data in Pandas with categoricals and timestamps for use in tableau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73339132/how-to-transform-data-in-pandas-with-categoricals-and-timestamps-for-use-in-tabl)

### Update

I know I have to switch year data to create column.

```
Type 1 Acute?   NHS England Region  Code    Name    Date    Value
0   No  East of England 8D379   CARETECH COMMUNITY SERVICES LTD 2020-08-01  0.0
1   No  East of England 8D379   CARETECH COMMUNITY SERVICES LTD 2020-08-02  0.0
2   No  East of England 8D379   CARETECH COMMUNITY SERVICES LTD 2020-08-03  0.0
3   No  East of England 8D379   CARETECH COMMUNITY SERVICES LTD 2020-08-04  0.0
4   No  East of England 8D379   CARETECH COMMUNITY SERVICES LTD 2020-08-05  0.0
```

I tried this combination. Would be too confusing for most people...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Any analysis in Tableau can be expressed in terms of percentages. For example, rather than viewing sales for every product, you might want to view each product’s sales as a percentage of the total sales for all products.

[Read about % change](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_percentages_options.htm)

[image]